# The area of a cyclic quadrilateral squared is a polynomial of Q's side lengths

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have an interesting "sketch" of a proof of  Brahmagupta's formula that I would love to have some help with. It relies on the following lemma:

**Lemma:** The square of the area for a cyclic quadrilateral Q is a polynomial of Q's sidelengths.

I would really appreciate help in making an proof of the lemma with minimal calculations. Obviously one could prove the above lemma by simply appealing to Brahmagupta's formula, but that would defeat the purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: You might be interested in Robbins' Conjecture(s) on this topic. See this 2004 article on arXiv ["The Area of Cyclic Polygons: Recent Progress on Robbins' Conjectures" (PDF)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408104.pdf) by Igor Pak. The introduction discusses why, in general, the square of a cyclic polygon's area, and the squares of its edge-lengths, are related via a polynomial.

Comment: Thank you @Blue, this is perfect!